# Multiple distinct instances of object graph in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

This is a somewhat simplified version of my setup. I have an application that consumes a library, and the library provides a client for accessing some web service. My application wraps this in an XyzService that provides some higher level operations.

The library provides a parameterised Windsor installer, which registers WebApiClient and its dependencies. The installer takes a configuration object that (amongst other things) specifies the URI for the web service.

This is fine so long as I only ever want to talk to a single instance of the web service. But in this case there are actually two different instances of the web service, and they are not interchangeable. At startup I want the app to be constructed with references to two distinct instances of XyzService, the first with an object-graph configured to access (say) `http://server.green/` and the second with an object-graph configured to access (say) `http://server.red/`.

Here's a diagram:

[image: Example object]

On the left is what I get if I just have two constructor parameters of type IXyzService. I get two instances of WebApiClient (since it's got transient lifetime), but they both share the same configuration (since the installer created an instance and registered that).

On the right is what I want. But I'm not sure how to provide two IWebApiClientConfigurations and tell Castle Windsor that when it's resolving IXyzServices for App it should create two separate object graphs, the first with one configuration and the second with the other.

### What I tried

I thought at first that a [typed factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) might be what I wanted. I created an interface like this:

```
public interface IXyzServiceFactory
{
    IXyzService GetXyzService(IWebApiClientConfiguration webApiClientConfiguration);
    void Release(IXyzService xyzService);
}
```

and registered it like this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IXyzServiceFactory>()
             .AsFactory());
```

I changed my App to take this factory and use it to request two instances of IXyzService, passing a different configuration each time. I thought that the configuration might be used when it tried to construct the WebApiService. However:

- It didn't work - the configuration object I passed in was ignored and I still got the configuration instance provided by the library's installer.
- Even if it had worked, it would have been nasty, because it cluttered up my app with knowledge of the configuration objects and of the lifetime of the XyzService.

### What I want

Ideally, I want to know how to tell Windsor that when it calls App's constructor:

```
public App(IXyzService xyzService1, IXyzService xyzService2)
```

...that it should construct an object graph for each as normal, except that when it comes to resolve IWebApiClientConfiguration, the first graph should get one instance and the second graph should get another. I want to instantiate and register the instances of IWebApiClientConfiguration in the App's Windsor installer.

I'd prefer not to duplicate the library's Windsor installer in my app, I want everything it registers *except* the WebApiClientConfiguration. But if there's no way around it I would put up with doing that.

While I am constrained in what I can do with the library, I would still be interested in answers that recommend how to handle this sort of situation without those constraints.

### Notes

I'm currently using Castle Windsor 2.5.3. I know this is quite old. If the solution requires it I would be willing to try to upgrade, assuming there are no breaking changes that would stop me from using the library and its existing installer. If there are it would be quite difficult to upgrade.

I've tried to remove extraneous details without making things so abstract that the motivation is no longer clear. Please let me know if there are ways I can clarify the question without making it excessively long.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3.x versions of Castle Windsor you can register multiple implementations *as named* and then explicitly specify named dependencies on your other registrations. It would then look like this (of course this registration is missing the implementations, lifestyles... but those are not important here):

```
container.Register(
    // Register a config containing http://server.green/, set its name,
    // and register a named IXyzService depending on the config.
    Component.For<IWebApiClientConfiguration>().Named("greenConfig"),
    Component.For<IXyzService>().Named("greenService")
        .DependsOn(typeof (IWebApiClientConfiguration), "greenConfig"),

    // Register another config of the same interface containing http://server.red/,
    // and a named IXyzService that uses it.
    Component.For<IWebApiClientConfiguration>().Named("redConfig"),
    Component.For<IXyzService>().Named("redService")
        .DependsOn(typeof (IWebApiClientConfiguration), "redConfig"));
```

Then you can resolve the service using its name as a key:

```
var greenService = container.Resolve<IXyzService>("greenService");
var redService = container.Resolve<IXyzService>("redService");
```

and each of the instances will use its specified named dependency.

There should be a (different) way to specify dependencies in your Castle Windsor 2.5.3 version as well, although I haven't worked with it, so I don't how to achieve that.

Comment: Does this work even though IWebClientConfiguration is not a direct dependency of the XyzService? Does the DependsOn apply recursively to dependencies of dependencies?

Comment: Not by default, and I haven't found a way to specify an indirect dependency yet...